# Why shouldn't I use ID selectors in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was shocked by this line "Don't use ID selectors in CSS". Is it true? I found many posts have written this.

1. http://mattwilcox.net/archive/entry/id/1054/
2. http://screwlewse.com/2010/07/dont-use-id-selectors-in-css/
3. http://oli.jp/2011/ids/

I think we can use the ID for the selectors.

I still want to clear this up.

Comment: And your question/problem is ?

Comment: i think this question is more suitable to programmers.stackexchange

Comment: Yeah, this is an open ended "question" which will just result in personal opinions being stated

Comment: I disagree that this question is open ended .. because using classes has a advantage of reusability

Comment: @MikulGohil as expressed above, this question is open ended, it will solicit debate/opinions (just look at the answers you got: first one is for, second one is against and so on. it's not constructive) which is against SO rules. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) for more information.

Comment: @Archan Mishra The fact that you "disagree" for that reason, makes this question open-ended.

Comment: The first article in your post is really great!

Comment: This question is about rationale for disallowing ids in selectors. Pretending this is not clear is quite strange, fllows :)

Comment: This is a very useful question. I don't understand why they closed this one. The author of the question had no idea the answers would be controversial; and even if he did, what is wrong with controversy? Whoever made this site's rules is a sick person.

Answer (score 49):

Id selectors have priority over other kinds of selectors. This can make it harder to add new rules using less specific selectors, leading to specificity wars: http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Comment: This is the best answer, IMO. Specificity wars are a code smell.

Answer (score 35):

I use `id` selectors all the time. I know which elements are going to be unique and which are not, and an `id` selector for unique elements (in my opinion) is best.

Comment: I dont think that your answer is correct because you have a unique element Now, how can you ensure that the future requirement might not want a similiar look for another element?

Comment: One: most of my design is controlled by me (that is, I set the requirements). Two: there are elements that are not repeated (page wrappers, header, footer, main navigation, etc.). I use ID's for all those. Even if I were (for some very strange reason) to want to use the EXACT same styling I used on a header for something else, then I could always add a class to the css definition later and still keep my header defined by an ID.

Comment: As you yourself say @scott you define your Own requirement which is not always possible for all .. hence using IDs is not a good Practise

Comment: It may not be a good practice in some situations, but to make a blanket statement that it is not good practice at all is incorrect. If you don't use wrappers, headers, footers, etc., then indeed, you may not have any unique elements on a page and therefore it would not be wise to use IDs.

Comment: [getElementsByClassName vs getElementById](https://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-getelementbyid) & [getElementById vs. getElementsByClassName vs. querySelector vs. jQuery](https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/25). For a single unique selector `getElementById` is marginally faster, but for 2 or more elements, `getElementsByClassName` is the way to go. Performance wise `getElementById` seems a keeper to me for single element which is unique on your site.

Comment: As long as id selectors are being used sparingly in shared stylesheets, I think @ScottS's approach is perfectly fine. I typically use id selectors when writing CSS defined directly on a page. In fact, using an id selector on a "one-time" element (like a wrapper for a particular section on a particular page) actually makes the markup more readable. It can tell future developers that a style was only being used for a very small context, and isn't being used widely.

Answer (score 14):

It is not advisable to use IDs as CSS selectors 
because if another element in the page uses the same/similar style,
you would have to write the same CSS again.

Even if you don't have more than one element with that style right now, it might come later.
Hence it is always advisable to use class.

Comment: If an element shares an ID, it won't pass validation.  And you should stress valid HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted, nor do I understand Shawn's comment. His point is salient I think. First paragraph - if another element in the page uses same / similar style, you couldn't reuse the ID. Second paragraph - if requirements change, you'll have to refactor as opposed to just applying the class you wrote in the first place. Seems legit to me.

Comment: Yes, @ShawnStrickland's comment is completely pointless.