# Append an element inside a specific div's element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know how to append an element inside another element, but how do I specify which class I want to append it to?

For example:

```
<div class="main" id="11">
  <div class="somethingelse>
       <div class="moreThings">
         /*How to append to this class?*/
      </div>
      <div class="extraThings">

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I have is something like this:

```
 var x = document.createElement("IMG");
 x.setAttribute("src", "../truck.png");
 document.getElementById(order_id).appendChild(x);
 document.getElementById("btn_transport_"+order_id).style.display = "none";
```

There could be hundreds of classes with same name which is why I need to define them by id.

At the moment I am appending the img under everything other divs, but I would like to append it inside "morethings". How would I do that?

Comment: I believe it's bad practice to use ID's in your HTML, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279132/why-shouldnt-i-use-id-selectors-in-css

Comment: @NielsBom That question is about CSS code not JavaScript.

Comment: You're still creating HTML elements with ID's right? It's both HTML.

Comment: @NielsBom Yes but when it comes to JavaScript, IDs are very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
document.getElementById(order_id).getElementsByClassName("moreThings")[0].appendChild(x);
```

Make sure `getElementsByClassName("moreThings")` returns at least one element.

You can find out more about `getElementsByClassName(...)` from [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). The gist of it is:

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names

Comment: Why the array [0]?

Comment: @Luke `getElementsByClassName(...)` returns a list of all the elements with that class name, I used `[0]` to get the first element in that list.

Comment: @Luke I'm glad I could help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). It allows CSS-like selectors. In your case it could look like

```
const myElementToAppendTo = document.querySelector('#myID .morethings');
myElementToAppendTo.appendChild(x);
```