# Is there a more efficient way of making buttons a different color?

Tags: html, css, button

Although the title explains most of my question, you might need some background information. I've been developing a website for some time now. The website has **3 buttons** in a **different color** for **each section**. Now, is there a more efficient way of doing the following:

```css
/* Button 1 */
#button1 {
  display: inline; 
  margin-left: 26px; 
  color: orangered; 
  border: 3px solid orangered; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  padding: 7px 30px 7px 30px; 
  border-radius: 30px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
}
#button1:hover {
  background-color: orangered; 
  color: white;
}

/* Button 2 */
#button2 {
  display: inline; 
  margin-left: 26px; 
  color: dodgerblue; 
  border: 3px solid dodgerblue; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  padding: 7px 30px 7px 30px; 
  border-radius: 30px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
}
#button2:hover {
  background-color: dodgerblue; 
  color: white;
}

/* Button 3 */
#button3 {
  display: inline; 
  margin-left: 26px; 
  color: #DD3157; 
  border: 3px solid #DD3157; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  padding: 7px 30px 7px 30px; 
  border-radius: 30px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
}
#button3:hover {
  background-color: #DD3157; color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="button1">Read more</a>
<a href="#" id="button2">Read more</a>
<a href="#" id="button3">Read more</a>
```

There probably is an easy solution for this

Comment: Generally, it's best to use id selectors (`#`) as little as possible. See for example [Why shouldn't I use ID selectors in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8279132) and https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-IDs-in-selectors

Answer (score 5):

Use a CSS class for all the properties that the buttons share:

```css
/* Button 1 */

.button {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 26px; 
  border: 3px solid;
  padding: 7px 30px 7px 30px; 
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.button:hover {
  border-color: transparent;
  color: white;
}

/* Button 1 */
.button1 { 
  color: orangered; 
}
.button1:hover {
  background: orangered; 
}

/* Button 2 */
.button2 {
  color: dodgerblue; 
}
.button2:hover {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

/* Button 3 */
.button3 {
  color: #DD3157; 
}
.button3:hover {
  background: #DD3157;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button button1">Read more</a>
<a href="#" class="button button2">Read more</a>
<a href="#" class="button button3">Read more</a>
```

Comment: I can just add a _border-color: orangered;_ to the different buttons.

Comment: @Gilles - since the border has the same color of the background when hovered, we can just make the border color transparent when the button is hovered.

Comment: Awesome! I would never came up with that.

Answer (score 5):

Use CSS variables and you will need only one general definition then you can have as many buttons as you want:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-left: 26px; 
  color: var(--c,black); 
  border: 3px solid var(--c,black); 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  padding: 7px 30px 7px 30px; 
  border-radius: 30px; 
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: var(--c,black); 
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button" style="--c:red">Read more</a>
<a href="#" class="button" style="--c:blue">Read more</a>
<a href="#" class="button" style="--c:darkblue">Read more</a>
<a href="#" class="button" style="--c:yellow">Read more</a>
<a href="#" class="button" style="--c:green">Read more</a>
<a href="#" class="button" >Read more</a>
```

Comment: Nice use of CSS variables.

Comment: For reduced typing, and to minimise repetition, consider using the `currentColor` in place of using the second call to `var()` in the `border` declaration.

Comment: @DavidThomas nope, it won't be good on hover :) I will be obliged in this case to redefine in it on hover ... by the way, using currentColor is not necessary as by default it's the currentColor.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.orange {
  color: orangered;
  border-color: orangered;
}

.orange:hover {
  background-color: orangered;
}

.blue {
  color: dodgerblue;
  border-color: dodgerblue;
}

.blue:hover {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.red {
  color: #DD3157;
  border-color: #DD3157;
}

.red:hover {
  background-color: #DD3157;
}

a {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 26px;
  border: 3px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 7px 30px 7px 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="orange">Read more</a>
<a href="#" class="blue">Read more</a>
<a href="#" class="red">Read more</a>
```