# Why's the children of a parent duplicating parents background image?

Tags: html, css

I have created a web page like this:
[image]

And the code is like this:

```css
       * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }
    
    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    div {
        background-image: url(download.jpeg);
        background-size: cover;
        height: 25%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .combo {
        height: 70%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    
    .textbox {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
    }
    
    h1 {
        text-align: center; 
        font-size: 200%;
        color: cornsilk;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .navbar {
        height: 30%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .column {
        height: 100%;
        width: 25%;
        float: left;
        display: table;
    }
    
    h2 {
        color: cornsilk;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    

    <title>Demo</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@100&display=swap" 

    rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class = "combo">
                <div class = "textbox">
                    <h1>WELCOME TO MY WEB</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "navbar">
                <div class = "column">
                    <h2>Home</h2>
                </div>
                <div class = "column">
                    <h2>Gallery</h2>
                </div>
                <div class = "column">
                    <h2>Activities</h2>
                </div>
                <div class = "column">
                    <h2>About</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But the problem here is that the background image that I set in `div` is getting duplicated in all its children. I want it to be one continuous image. How may I achieve this? Also, what is the reason behind this behavior?

I have tried setting z-index in div element but that did not work. Also, I tried setting the column background to be black but somehow the background turns black for a moment and then it turns to the same background. Can someone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because using `div` as a CSS selector selects all divs. If you want the image to be behind all of them, give the containing div a class and set the background image on that:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class = "combo">
    <div class = "textbox">
      <h1>WELCOME TO MY WEB</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "navbar">
    <div class = "column">
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
    <div class = "column">
      <h2>Gallery</h2>
    </div>
    <div class = "column">
      <h2>Activities</h2>
    </div>
    <div class = "column">
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  background-image: url(download.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `id` attribute instead of `class`. `class` is generally used apply same style on a group of elements, on the other hand, `id` is used to apply style on specific element as id is unique identifier. It would be better if you change `class` attributes to `id` and apply CSS using `#` selector:

```html
#container {
    background-image: url(download.jpeg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Where does the W3C recommend using IDs instead of classes for styling?

Comment: Check this article: [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_selectors.asp). W3C said use id for single element and class for multiple. He want to apply style to single element, that's why I told him to use id not class. Sorry for putting that statement, I removed it. But I read it somewhere. :( I am sure you also agree that we must use id if we want to style single element.

Comment: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/about/default.asp) is not in any way affiliated with the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/). Their information is frequently incorrect, incomplete, or misleading. And I disagree. Classes are the best way to style any number of elements, since they have the same inherent specificity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279132/why-shouldnt-i-use-id-selectors-in-css

Comment: But if classes are the only best way than why W3C provided us IDs?? BTW I am unaware of the fact that W3Schools not affiliated to W3C. I already removed W3C name from the answer.

Comment: ID attributes have many other uses besides styling, such as fragment identifiers and `aria-labelledby` attributes.

Comment: but IDs have use of styling also and classes also used to retrieve group of elements beside styling. Both of them are used by programmers.

Comment: I did changed my asswer as our talk progressed and you provided me some useful information. My message is part of our ongoing conversation in comment section, not my answer to Midhun question